# Setting Up Databricks Connect

Tags: databricks, databricks-connect

After running `databricks-connect configure`, when I run `databricks-connect test`, I am getting `"The system cannot find the path specified."` and then nothing happens, no error nothing. Please help me resolve this. Since there is no error message as well I am short pressed on what to google as well. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Update: I resolved this by matching the `JAVA versions`. The `Databricks runtime` in the cluster is `6.5` and on checking the documentation, it said `JAVA 1.8.0_252` and so I had to look for a version closer to this and it is working now (both `JDK` and `JRE` are working).
There is still a caveat though. For tables that belong to a data lake I am still unable to make it work with
`sparklyr::spark_read_parquet(sc = sc, path = "/.../parquet_table", header = TRUE, memory = FALSE)`
It does work for the tables that belong to the `"default"` database in `databricks`. Not sure if this is just in my case but I am tired of all the tweaking I have been doing for the past week lol. Please comment if anyone has been able to get this working!

Answer (score 0):

One of the hints is that you have JDK 15

Comment: Java version was the issue.